Is there a point to using taproot transactions over P2WSH if I only want to use the script path?
Interested in making an HTLC, in which case there should not be a key spending path. According to this post, one can set the internal public key to an essentially arbitrary value and just use the script path. But then is there any advantage to using P2TR over P2WSH?

See also: Is there an economic incentive to use P2WSH over P2TR?

See question: Is there an economic incentive to use P2WSH over P2TR?
The answer is, if you're absolutely sure you don't need any of Taproot's features, then a P2TR input costs a bit more than a P2WSH input with the same script.
However, Taproot does have features that could be useful to you:

Script tree: Splitting a script into multiple alternative conditions and only revealing one of them when spending is perfect for HTLCs.
PTLCs: Point Time Locked Contracts are a more efficient and private alternative to HTLCs. A successful execution of a PTLC doesn't need to use the script path at all.
Privacy: Because P2TR combines key and script spending, an unspent P2TR output reveals less information than either a P2WPKH or P2WSH output. Additionally, P2TR outputs are already more common than P2WSH outputs, so you might want to choose the larger anonymity set.


I was also interested in PTLCs, but as I understand it they cannot be used on Ethereum (section 3.2.1 here) which would be quite limiting for my use case.
